# Scale images in different Devices Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am making a Tic Tac Toe application for fun in Android Studio and have a problem.If i use nexus5x for preview in layout editor my app is oriented perfect.If i change this to nexus4 or a tablet the orientation is messed up.
This is a picture of what i mean.
[Nexus 5x as preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpr5M.png) and  [Nexus 4 as preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZxNw.png)

A sample from my xml code is the below:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mpampis.tictactoe2.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:src="@drawable/kokkinov3"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/kokkinov3"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
```

Comment: Are you doing anything to scale your image to fit the amount of space that will be available in your grid at runtime?

Comment: I have a .png file in drawables and when i use it in GridLayout i place it with margins to orient it.

Comment: sometimes you need to build the xml for each res. res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)  - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw your images they are receiving wrong margins, i.e. smaller screen receiving the larger margins which are suitable for nexus 5. As you have hardcoded the margins for every screen size, which is not recommended. try to put your margins in dimension.xml and make another for smaller screen.

Well the whole point of using DP is so that you don't have to worry about this. Margins will be roughly the same across devices, but if you're relying on lining things up on one particular device resolution/density combination, you'll definitely be in for a surprise when you test on other devices.

That said, if you do need to specify different margins for different screen sizes, simply add an XML file in res/values -- something like dimens.xml:

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <dimen name="my_view_margin">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then add one of these XMLs for every specific device qualifier that you need to (e.g. values-large, values-sw600dp, values-xlarge, etc.) and modify the value as you see fit. When you want to use these dimensions in a layout, just use:

```
android:layout_margin="@dimen/my_view_margin"
```

And Android will pick the correct value for whatever device it happens to be running on.

Comment: With this way i sould make one margin set for every xh xxh etc. devices?

Comment: Thnx you dude...Do u have any idea on how to make xml files for different  values?LIke an xml for large screens , an xml for small screen etc

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 4 is 384dp wide, and Nexus 5X is 411dp wide, according to [this.](https://design.google.com/devices/)

When I had to make app with grid layout, I [manually calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/1889459) each item's dimensions and added some padding for spacing.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

int itemWidth = width / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) could assist you in this.

It allows you to set `LayoutParams` as percentages instead of as hard values.